# Keyboard hides as dialog dissappears

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard, ios6

In my application i am using sharekit inorder to post on Facebook.On main screen i have a textview and a custom keyboard. When i click on Facebook button it will check about the user authentication tokens if present post will be published on Facebook if not it will display a dialog box to get username and password by user. When i click cancel button on that dialog the keyboard automatically hides. 
My problems is I dont want keyboard to get hide. I had also used observer

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

    selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)

    name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification

    object:nil];
```

This observer will show keyboard.
The observer always called method keyboardWillShow but in case of dialog it wont. And my keyboard automatically hides when I cancel the dialog.And I am using iOS6 in iOS5 the same observer is working fine.

Comment: in ios6 some feature in deprecated....

Answer (score 0):

In that cancel method write code like below

```
[yourview endEditing:NO];
```

let me know is it working or not....

Happy Coding!!!!!!